# How to get rid of the outmost parenthesis with a regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

In the most simple case, the pattern would be `\(.+?\)` but what do I do if I have a string like that `(a, b=[0, 1, 2], c=(0,), d=(1, 2, 3))` ? I need to make it `a, b=[0, 1, 2], c=(0,), d=(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: you just want to remove the outermost parenthesis ?

Comment: yep, that would be enough. Is it possible?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hR8B0w/1

Comment: @marvel308 aaah I can't believe I couldn't figure it out...I must be too tired...well if you want you can post it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: The question is marked as a duplicate, so can't

Comment: @marvel308 well, so do I have to delete it?